# i have a nodejs and react js app and i get error of SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to send data from my backend side with nodejs to my frontend side when I use fetch in the frontend side, I use reactjs.
and I get an error of "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON" in the fetch function in useEffect function.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Item from "./item";
import style from "./show-item.module.css";

const ShowItem = (props) => {
  const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/")
      .then((res) => {
        if(res.ok){
          console.log('ok')
          return res.json()
        }
      }).then(result => console.log(result))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);

  return (
    <ul className={style["ul-item"]}>
      {orders.map((item) => (
        <Item
          key={item.id}
          id={item.id}
          name={item.name}
          detail={item.detail}
          price={item.price}
          amount={1}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default ShowItem;
```

I used in proxy in my react js app in package.json

```
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
```

this is my backend code

```
const adminRouts = require('./routes/admin');
const shopRouts = require('./routes/shop');
const shefRouts = require('./routes/chef');

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json(), bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.use('/admin',adminRouts);
app.use('/shef', shefRouts);
app.use(shopRouts);

console.log('listen ', port)
app.listen(port);
```

my shaf code

```
const express = require("express");

const router = express.Router();


const order = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "הלחם שלנו",
      detail: "לחם פראנה באפייה מסורתית,שמן זית ומטבלים טעימים",
      price: 26,
    },
  ];

router.use("/", (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('here');
    res.json(order);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: i mean, you fetched `/`, not `/shaf/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## HTML Is being returned, Signifying the wrong API route being called

First of all, it is worth noting that the backend is responding with HTML. Why is that? If you check in your express code there is no route where HTML is sent. The URL that you are using the fetch is '/'. This '/' route will get the base URL of 'localhost:5000' and nothing else. It seems that you are doing a request to the same URL that React is hosted in. This means that you are doing a get request to the 'public/' folder in the react app, and it is returning the HTML in the default 'index.html' that react uses.

You will need to change either the react proxy or the base URL for the server. I recommend changing all the API routes to be appended to '/api'. So the '/shef' becomes '/api/shef'. To make it dynamic make an API router with endpoint '/api' and move '/shef' to the API router file.

Although there are many ways to do this, here is one way:

**make a 'api.route.js' file in the '/routes' folder**

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const shopRouts = require('./routes/shop');
const shefRouts = require('./routes/chef');

router.get("/", async (req, res, next) => {
  res.send({ message: "Ok api is working " });
});

router.use('/admin',adminRouts);
router.use('/shef', shefRouts);
router.use('/shop', shopRouts);

module.exports = router;
```

**shaf code**

```
const apiRoutes = require('./routes/api');

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json(), bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.use('/api', apiRoutes);

console.log('listen ', port)
app.listen(port);
```

**Then in your frontend:**

The only line changed here is:
Use which ever method you like to get the base URL. You might want to keep it in a .env file.

```
fetch(window.location.origin + "/api/shef")
```

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Item from "./item";
import style from "./show-item.module.css";

const ShowItem = (props) => {
  const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(window.location.origin + "/api/shef")
      .then((res) => {
        if(res.ok){
          console.log('ok')
          return res.json()
        }
      }).then(result => console.log(result))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);

  return (
    <ul className={style["ul-item"]}>
      {orders.map((item) => (
        <Item
          key={item.id}
          id={item.id}
          name={item.name}
          detail={item.detail}
          price={item.price}
          amount={1}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default ShowItem;
```